# Almost everywhere convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is a question that my teacher is having us do for homework but I think there might be a typo in it. I was hoping if someone clear this up  for me.

The sequence $\{X_n\}$ of random variables converges almost everywhere to $X$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $ \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|\le \epsilon \; for \; all \; n \ge m) =1 $ or equivalently $ \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|> \epsilon \; for \; some \; n \ge m) =0 $.

I think that  $ \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|\le \epsilon \; for \; all \; n \ge m) =1 $ is the same thing as saying $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|\le \epsilon ) =1 $ which is then the same as saying $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|> \epsilon ) =0 $ which means convergence in probability. And this is where I think there is a mistake because convergence in probability does not imply almost everywhere convergence.

Comment: They are not the same as

$$
P\left\{\bigcap_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\}\right\}=P\left\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}\to 1
$$
is stronger than requiring $P\left\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}\to 1$.

Comment: @d.k.o. could you please expand on what you said, I don't understand.

Comment: I said that your assertion in the third paragraph is incorrect...

Comment: @d.k.o. yeah I got that part, could you explain where the intersection and sup came in. That's what I don't understand

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pointwise_Supremum_of_Measurable_Functions_is_Measurable

Comment: @d.k.o. you wrote $P\left\{\bigcap_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\}\right\}=P\left\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}\to 1$ but according to the link you posted it should be $P\left\{\bigcup_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\}\right\}=P\left\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}\to 1$.

Comment: @d.k.o. could you explain why $P\left\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}\to 1 $ $\not \Rightarrow$ $P\left\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}\to 1$

Comment: According to the link, $\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|>\epsilon\}=\bigcup_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\}$.

Comment: @d.k.o. sorry what I meant to say was that originally you said $\left\{\bigcap_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\}\right\}=\left\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\}$ but according to the link $ \left\{\bigcap_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\}\right\}=\left\{\inf_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le \epsilon\right\} $. Is this right? And thank you for the counter example.

Comment: Nope.
$$
\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\le\epsilon\}=\{\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|>\epsilon\}^c \\=\left(\bigcup_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\}\right)^c=\bigcap_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\le\epsilon\}
$$

and

$$
\{\inf_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\ge\epsilon\}=\{\inf_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|<\epsilon\}^c \\=\left(\bigcup_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|<\epsilon\}\right)^c=\bigcap_{n\ge m}\{|X_n-X|\ge\epsilon\}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (standard) counterexample: consider a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent r.v.s. with
$$
P\{X_n=1\}=n^{-1} \text{ and }P\{X_n=0\}=1-n^{-1}.
$$
Then $X_n\xrightarrow{p} 0$ because $\forall \epsilon>0$,
$$
P\{X_n\le\epsilon\}\ge 1-n^{-1}\to 1 \text{ as }n\to \infty.
$$
However, $X_n\not\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$ because for any $m$,
$$
P\left\{\sup_{n\ge m}X_n\le 1/2\right\}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=m}^{N}(1-n^{-1})=0.
$$